# Delete my iCloud account

Tags: icloud

Do I have to pay to have an iCloud account? I use iCloud mail but I don't want to pay storage for photos.  How can I cancel this arrangement

Comment: Do you want to *delete* your account, or do you just want to be sure you don‘t pay for additional storage while still using it for mail?

Comment: Switching off iCloud Photo Library in the Photos setting in iCloud may help. You should do it on every Apple device you own. While using My Photo Stream is unlikely to take you over the 5 GB free storage limit, iCloud Photo Library backs up your entire photos library to iCloud, so may result in prompts to pay for storage.

Answer (score 2):

There is no charge for iCloud/AppleID. Just remove your credit card, end all subscriptions, cancel any paid storage upgrades and you’re set.

Set a very secure password and be sure you download everything you care to ever have and consider if you want that account back, it’s best to write down the security questions and answers and password just in case.

Once you sign out of all devices except one, you can delete everything at https://icloud.com and then Apple will delete all your files from their servers. Then remove the account from the last device and walk away from that account.